# Swing stop timer when exiting jframe

Tags: java, swing, timer, camera, jframe

I have a certain task which I run at scheduled intervals. Basically I show a camera feed on a Label in a JFrame. However when I exit the JFrame the application seems to run. How can I stop it? I have stripped out the details of the code, just leaving the relevent parts in

```
public class TaskCLass extends JFrame {

    JPanel p;
    JLabel l;
    Timer timer;

    public TaskCLass() {

        p = new JPanel();
        l = new JLabel("Window");
        add(p);
        p.add(l);
        setSize(700, 600);

        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                timer.purge();
                timer.cancel();
                System.exit(1);
            }

            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                timer.purge();
                timer.cancel();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        startTask();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new TaskCLass();
    }


    public void startTask() {


        TimerTask t = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
              //.........

            }
        };

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(t, 0, 200);
    }


}
```

Comment: How can you have a Camera constructor inside the TaskClass class? it should generate a compile error

Comment: Sorry about that, I did a bit of editing because I wanted to strip out the irrelevant code and forgot the constructor.

Comment: Change the default close operation to do nothing on close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) if the scheduled code is modifying the GUI. Otherwise if you are using the non-Swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) than you need to shut it down with [cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29).